# Selecting, slicing, and aggregating temporal data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to handle temporal data with pandas and I'm having a hard time...
Here is a sample of the DataFrame  :

```
index     ip    app     dev os    channel    click_time
0       29540    3       1  42      489  2017-11-08 03:57:46              
1       26777   11       1  25      319  2017-11-09 11:02:14              
2      140926   12       1  13      140  2017-11-07 04:36:14              
3       69375    2       1  19      377  2017-11-09 13:17:20              
4      119166    9       2  15      445  2017-11-07 12:11:37
```

This is a click prediction problem, so I want to create a time window aggregating the past behaviour of a specific ip ( for a given ip, how many clicks in the last 4 hours, 8 hours ? ).

I tried creating one new column which was simply :

```
df['minus_8']=df['click_time']-timedelta(hours=8)
```

I wanted to use this so that for each row I have a specific 8 hours window on which to aggregate my data.

I have also tried resampling with little success, my understanding of the function isn't optimal let's say.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Did you try `df.set_index('click_time').resample('8H').count()`?

Comment: I have and this does work, but this isn't exactly what I'm trying to do here.
With this I get results over the whole df regardless of the ip and everything else.
I want to create a new column df['clicks_in_last_8h'] for each row.

Comment: I'd request you to add your expected output for this dataset, because as it stands, I really can't understand your question :/

Comment: You're right, I should rephrase...
As an input I would get a row from my df, and as an output the number of times the ip corresponding to this row logged in in the last 8 hours.
For this I'm assuming I'll need to create some kind of lookback window and select the relevant data inside that window to then aggregate it, but that's exactly what I can't manage to do right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to select a particular 8 hours, you can do as follows:

```
start_time = datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 9,11, 2, 14)
df[(df['click_time' >= start_time)
   & (df['click_time'] <= start_time+datetime.timedelta(0, 60*60*8))]
```

Otherwise I really think you need to look more at `resample`. Mind you, if you want `resample` to have your data divided into 8 hour chunks that are always consistent (e.g. from 00:00-08:00, 08:00-16:00, 16:00-00:00), then you will probably want to crop your data to a certain start time.

Comment: Two problems arise for this solution :
- The start_time is not set as it depends on the time where the user connected.
- Because resample divides the whole lot in 8 hour chunks this doesn't fit what I need

Answer (score 0):

Using parts of the solution given by Martin, I was able to create this function that outputs what I wanted :

```
def window_filter_clicks(df, h):
    df['nb_clicks_{}h'.format(h)]=0
    ip_array = df.ip.unique()
    for ip in ip_array:
        df_ip=df[df['ip']==ip]
        for row, i in zip(df_ip['click_time'],df_ip['click_time'].index):
            df_window    = df_ip[(df_ip['click_time']>= row-timedelta(hours=h)) & (df_ip['click_time']<= row) ]
            nb_clicks_4h = len(df_window)
            df['nb_clicks_{}h'.format(h)].iloc[i]= nb_clicks_4h
return df
```

h allows me to select the size of the window on which to iterate.
Now this works fine, but it is **very** slow and I am working with a **lot** of rows.
Does anyone know how to improve the speed of such a function ? ( Or if there is anything similar built-in ? )